# Why application thread (main thread) is stopped, while javascript garbage collection algorithm is running?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, javascript-engine

I am asking in the context of **Google V8 Engine** and it's **Mark and Sweep algorithm**.

As v8 engine has some gc threads, that can do garbage collection concurrently with main thread operations.

Comment: I think you would be better off asking the V8 team. https://v8.dev/ they have a twitter account, maybe they'd respond there

Comment: yes, thanks for the suggestion. I will do that too, that will also help. If I get an answer from them, I can update here or If someone already knows they can also help us understand this.